# overloading operator = return by value or reference?

Tags: c++, copy, constants, overloading, operator-keyword

1) What is the difference between:

```
complex& operator = (const complex& c);
```

and

```
complex operator = (complex c);
```

2) are they the same if I define (in the second case) a copy constructor?

```
complex::complex (const complex& c){

    //code
    }
```

3) what is the funcion of const?

Answer (score 5):

### Those are very different

Do you want chained assignments? Return `*this`.

```
a = b = c; // Chained assignment
```

Default assignment in C++ supports chaining, so it's a good idea to keep this rule.

To support this type of assignment each operation has to return a reference to `*this` or return a copy:

```
complex& operator = (const complex& c)
{
  // do assignment

   return *this;
}
```

or

```
complex operator = (const complex& c)
{
  // do assignment

   return *this;
}
```

But this simple job should be light and efficient. Assume no RVO or moving is available, then returning a reference rather than a copy is preferred.

Another reason that I prefer returning a reference is to get rid of a confusing thing in my mind. See these two scenarios:

```
// Returning a reference
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
(a = b) = c;
```

After assignments, `a=3` `b=2` `c=3`. Because, first `b` assigns to `a` and returns a reference to `a`, then `c` assigns to that reference and `a` changes again.

```
// Returning a copy
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
(a = b) = c;
```

After assignments, `a=2` `b=2` `c=3`. Because, first `b` assigns to `a` and returns a temporary copy, then `c` assigns to that temporary object (no effect on `a` or `b`).

As you can see, the results are different. Ignoring what happens and which one is better. You should choose a way which is popular and expected for programmers. I believe C++ programmers by watching `(a = b) = c` expect first result.

Therefore you should use first one.

About keyword `const`:

When you pass an object by reference to a function, the function can modify it. You can put a `const` to protect it against unwanted changes.

Answer (score 1):

1) the first one is the idiomatic C++ version. it says that it takes a reference to the argument (not make a copy) and will return a reference to a complex (not a copy) which is usually the object being assigned to (i.e. `*this`).

the second one can work but it makes unnecessary copies & u can't call functions on the object that gets assigned to, like this: `(a = b).dosth()` because it returns a different object. i mean it will compile but it will call `dosth` on a temp object.

2) they aren't the same ever, however the second one wont work if u dont have accessible copy ctor (or sometimes move ctor).

3) `const` is a promise that you won't modify the argument. so in `a = b` you don't want to modify `b` and `const` enforces that. u don't need it in the second version (pass by value) because you can't modify it anyway, because its just a copy.

Comment: what about:
 complex& operator = (complex c)


1)if I define a copy-constructor, it will be called when I use:
a=b; (right?!) 

2) however if I use (a=b).method() it won't work because even if I return *this, the return value will be destroyed as soon as it is returned?

Comment: @user2734408 `complex& operator = (complex c)` will work if u have copy ctor and do `a = b`. if u do `(a=b).method()` (and your `operator=` has `return *this` at the end) it will work too. it will not be destroyed as soon as it is returned because when a ref goes out of scope no dtor is called. so it will work and call the function on `a`. so it will work fine but its not the normal way to do it i think

Comment: Actually, the pass-by-value is becoming the idiomatic version for `operator=`. It’s usually the superior variant. Look up “copy-and-swap” idiom.

Comment: @KonradRudolph To me it seems like you are replacing something which is always good with something that is sometimes "only slightly worse". You could do the copy-and-swap if you choose to even if you pass by reference (by creating a third class as a copy and doing the swap). So really I see no advantage in passing by value, and a lot of disadvantages.

Comment: @cluracan for copy and swap, it is always superior to accept the parameter by value because the compiler can use move-semantics, whereas if you take it by reference you cannot. however you and i dislike copy-and-swap anyway (as you say, replacing something that's always fine with something that's sometimes (most of the time?) worse) so its moot. EDIT - actually now that I think about it, copy and swap might be always equally fast and sometimes faster. but you have to write a `swap` function anyway so it's not really less work.

Comment: @kal why do you say it's "always equally fast"? That would depend on how well you can do a swap. And if your function is inlined, then the compiler can do move semantics anyway when needed - even in the reference case.

Comment: @cluracan Why would you ever pass by reference if you then copy the object directly anyway? That has *no* advantage compared to pass-by-value, is one line longer and (ever so slightly) less efficient. (Note I’m not even talking about move semantics here.)

Comment: @cluracan i don't think a compiler can make a reference refer to an xvalue even if it's inline.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I already listed the advantages. I will do so again: (1) you may not have an efficient swap, and one may not even be possible (2) in your case there are 3 object instead of 2. If each object take a lot of memory you have added 50% to your memory (3) if constructing an object takes time (opening sockets, files, etc., allocating memory) but copying does not (as you keep the same files, sockets, memory) then you also take much more time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph because the copy ctor + swap may be more expensive than you could make an assign operator.

Comment: @KonradRudolph here's an example: I have vectors. They all *happen* to be on size 100. The `operator=` would see it has enough memory for the new values, so it doesn't need to allocate. Your copy-swap semantics will do an allocation (for the new object), copy, swap and deallocate. **this is much much slower!**

Comment: i guess you have to take it on a class-by-class basis. if ur class is cheaply swappable and perhaps no optimizations can be made in special cases, then copy+swap is fine. if u have a bottleneck or its not cheaply swappable or can optimize, then do it the old-fashion way

Comment: @kal Actually, inline means it can optimize the code differently depending on the context. I *wouldn't* recommend doing it "on a class-by-class" basis: idioms are extremely important for the readability of the code and for bug avoidance. If you want to do copy-then-swap, pass by reference, do a copy, and swap. Making it inline so the reference would be optimized away.

Comment: @cluracan i think that's the wrong way to do it. if u take a reference then u cannot assign it to a temporary. e.g. if `S` is your class, `S s; s = S()` doesn't compile b/c cannot bind a ref to a temp. u must take a copy unless u want to write two versions, one for rvalue ref and one for normal ref. also, we may discuss theoretical compiler optimizations but even if u take a `S&&`, the compiler will not elide copies or use move semantics. I just tested it w/ this code: http://pastebin.com/XTUrcg0Y on clang 3.3 & g++ 4.8.1 w/ `-O4` flag. if u run it u will see that the `COPY_AND_SWAP` version

Comment: (continued) elides the copy but the `REF_COPY_AND_SWAP` version cannot/does not, it makes a full copy. so whether copy-and-swap is good or not, taking the param by ref and making a copy inside is the wrong way to do copy-and-swap.  for reference read http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @Kal With your code you are right. But that isn't the code. The rules are different for function inputs. A `const reference` input to a function *can* be bound to a temporary, and more over - if the code is inlined it is simply replaced with either that temporary or the non-temporary that was inputed.

Comment: @cluracan my mistake, i forgot the `const`. but i fixed it and tried it again, and it doesn't make a difference, compiler does not elide the copy. with or without the inlining the copy is still made. if u don't think so please show some code that is optimized by a compiler that exists today instead of just theorizing.

Comment: @Kal - again, there are different rules for input to function and for variables. I just wrote code that does both, looked at the assembly and saw it was exactly the same. What I mean is doing something like this: `inline C &operator=(const C &c){ C tmp(c);swap(*this,tmp);return *this;}`. This compiles into exactly the same as `inline C &operator=(C c){swap(*this,c);return *this;}` for both a temporary and a non-temporary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38131/discussion-between-cluracan-and-kal)

Answer (score 0):

They aren't the same, the first one passes references so the objects remain in place in memory and the second will *need* the copy-ctor as `complex` objects will be copied in and out of the function.  The first is canonical and what you want, the second isn't used because it's unnecessarily wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

the `const` is a way of saying "I promise I won't change `c`! So don't worry about it!". This allows the user to provide the actual class (in your case `complex`) by reference without worrying it will change unexpectedly.

"reference" - chosen by adding the `&` sign - means that this function actually uses the same object that the user gave, from the same memory. Since it is using the same object, it is important that you promised not to change that object.

Without the `&` - your second example - you don't pass the same object, you pass a *copy* of that object. So the `const` is unnecessary (although still legal) because the user doesn't care if you change a copy.

The difference? Time (and memory for large classes). If you pass the reference to the object - you don't need to copy that object. That saves you time (the time it takes to copy the object) and memory (the memory the object needs).

Comment: sometimes it can be faster to make a copy (i.e. not use reference) but not usually. only for small classes i think

Comment: @kal yes, you are right. Using reference means you still have to copy the pointer itself - so it does take some time and some memory. If your object is smaller than a pointer then reference actually takes *more* memory. Also, during the execution of the function, a reference adds a level of indirection so it takes longer than having the object on the stack. But these are considerations for more advanced needs :)

Comment: Well, *the whole point* of `operator=` is to make a copy. So passing by value is just fine (same comment as for Kal’s answer: look up the “copy-and-swap” idiom).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - that would require an efficient swap, which not all object have or are able to have. In addition - it's still a tad slower as it requires a separate swap after the copy. Finally, if each instance of the class need a big chunk of data no matter what (that isn't shared for some reason) then you'll have a much larger memory imprint. So... no, that's not a superior method.

Comment: @KonradRudolph also - if you do want to write the copy only once - write only `operator=` and use it in the copy constructor (by doing `*this=other`). It is much better than the other way around (as it doesn't require an efficient swap, and doesn't create 3 different objects)

Comment: @cluracan Yes, it needs an efficient swap. But in that case it can be *faster* than the pass-by-reference variant (references incur overhead due to indirection). It’s also superior because it’s automatically exception safe and much simpler code, which is a huge boon. And no, the other way round (implementing copy construction in terms of copy assignment) is not superior, because it would imply a redundant default initialisation of the object beforehand. Read up on the idiom before arguing against it.

Comment: It will not be faster. The indirection will be optimized away if the funcion is inline. Lastly, like I said, if you do want to use the copy-and-swap then you still can while passing by reference and they creating a copied instance and using swap. So you can still do *the exact same thing* while passing by reference - which means passing by value is by definition "equal or worse" than passing by reference.

Comment: @cluracan I haven’t got the time to explain this now but if you actually researched the copy-and-swap idiom instead of relying on your (flawed) understanding, you might see how it works better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - don't be patronizing. I did research the "copy-and-swap" the moment you mentioned it. It is a solution to *exception safety*. It, by definition, takes *more* resources (time/memory) but in return gives you ***strong** exception safety* (assuming your `swap` is no-throw). That is the motivation of this idiom. If exception safely is less important to you than, say, time or memory then this is the WRONG solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

The second form takes and returns value by copy rather than by reference, which is often inefficient.

```
complex operator=(complex c);
```

The parameter `c` is passed in as a copy of the original. For simple datatypes like `int` this doesn't matter, but if `complex` is, well, complex, this can result in unnecessary allocations/deallocations and hinder performance.

Passing by reference, as in:

```
complex& operator=(complex& c);
```

Means that the object passed to the operator isn't copied.

The second difference is what they return. The correct form of the operator is to return a reference to itself. The first form you provide actually returns a copy of the object, which again can be inefficient.

Finally, again the correct form of the operator takes the input object as a `const` reference. This is more a stylistic issue than anything to do with performance - but one would not reasonably expect the assignment operator to modify the input object, and specifying it as `const` prevents this.

So to sum up,

```
complex& operator=(const complex& c);
```

is the correct form.

Comment: copy is not always less efficient

Comment: Same comment as for the other answers – look up the “copy-and-swap” idiom. Passing by value is usually entirely OK in the case of `operator=`, *especially* if the object is big (but can be swapped cheaply). In the case of a `complex` class, that’s probably not the case, though.